# Using ORDER BY with WHERE IN

Tags: sqlite, where-clause, sql-order-by

In my SQLite query:

```
"SELECT * FROM menu WHERE ID IN (" & optList & ") ORDER BY seqno"
```

optList is a list of ID's and something like:

```
"01","02","14","03"
```

The corresponding seqno values for these rows are: `01 02 03 04` and this is the order I need to have but the rows returned are in ID order, i.e. `01, 02, 14, 03`

Does the `ORDER BY` not work when using `WHERE IN` and/or is there some other way of returning the rows in the desired order?

Comment: Of course `ORDER BY` works in this case! Some clarification: Where are you calling SQL from ([tag:vb.net], [tag:android], ...)? Is `optList` a string or a string array? Are `ID` and `seqno` two digit strings?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Please create an example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5).

Comment: I'm using B4A. optlist is a string, eg "'01','02','14','03'". ID is an integer and seqno is 2 digit text.

Comment: Haven't used SQLFiddle before and although can see how to create the table not expert enough in SQL to insert data into it, sorry.

Comment: Got a working example in SQLFiddle and it did produce the correct order. Must check the working in B4A again, perhaps it is doing something odd!

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me

```
SELECT *
FROM `accolades`
WHERE id
IN ( 1, 3, 4, 5 )
 order by id asc
```

Comment: But you are ordering by the same column that you have in the WHERE clause.  In my case I want to order by another column which is not in the same order as the one I am using in the WHERE.

Comment: I have try and it works for me
SELECT *
FROM `accolades`
WHERE id
IN ( 1, 3, 4, 5 )
ORDER BY accoladable_id ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30